# Performance of multiprocessing vs single processing

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

I am fairly new to python and I am currently looking at multiprocessing. I have created a simple example that I assumed would be considerably quicker to do with multiprocessing than single processing, but as it turns out it is actually slower! The script creates and runs through a list with integers from 0 to 999, splitting it into shorter lists that worker processes then runs through and prints "I am worker [integer]". Typical run time is appr. 26 sec, while the single process script is .5-1 sec faster. Is there any particular reason why my multiprocessing script is slower? Or why it is a bad example to use for multiprocessing? The code for the two scripts are below for reference

Multiprocessing code:

```
import multiprocessing
from datetime import datetime

def f(x):
    listagain=[]
    for i in x:
        listagain.append("I am worker " + str(i))
    return listagain    

def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    """
    lister=[]
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        lister.append(l[i:i+n])
    return lister

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startTime=datetime.now()
    Pool=multiprocessing.Pool
    mylist=list(xrange(10000))
    size=10
    listlist=[]
    listlist=chunks(mylist,size)
    workers=4
    pool=Pool(processes=workers)
    result=pool.map(f,listlist)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print result
    print (datetime.now()-startTime)
```

Single processing code:

```
from datetime import datetime

def f(x):
    listagain=[]
    for i in x:
        for j in xrange(0,len(i)):
            listagain.append("I am worker " + str(i[j]))
    return listagain 

def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    """
    lister=[]
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        lister.append(l[i:i+n])
    return lister

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startTime=datetime.now()
    mylist=list(xrange(10000))
    size=10
    listlist=[]
    listlist=chunks(mylist,size)
    result=f(listlist)
    print result
    print (datetime.now()-startTime)
```

Comment: As @Saullo said, not only is there overhead in multiprocessing, but it only saves time if it allows multiple hardware processors to get working in parallel on the problem. If you've only got 2 cores, you can only get 2x at best, no matter how many threads there are. Also, be careful of I/O. If printing takes 90% of the time, the speedup due to parallelism can only really work on the remaining 10%.

Comment: Note that `map()` has an optional `chunksize` argument - no need to split up the list yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overhead associated with `multiprocessing` that is probably higher than the time consumed for a single task in your problem, but if you have bigger tasks this overhead (usually associated with pickling Python objects) will become proportionally smaller and it will be advantageous using multiprocessing.

Comment: thanks. When you say single task, do you mean a worker process from beginning to end? Also, my goal is to ultimately run through a folder with thousands of csv-files and pull some data from each to create new files. I have seen multiprocessing questions asked for large files, but little on multiple files. does this have to do with the overhead, i.e. tasks on a large file usually take longer and hence multiprocessing is better?

Comment: @user2840117 for multiple `csv` files you may get an advantage of `multiprocessing` if you do not pass all the loaded strings from the files. If you only pass the file name or the file object the cost to pickle and load will be probably small and you will shall see a gain using `multiprocessing`. The tip is to avoid dumping and loading big objects when spawning the processes....